# Hide element after this select box by change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am working on a time table where users can update their opening hours.

I have select boxes per day with 'open' or 'closed', and after this time select boxes with 'from' and 'till'.

I want to make it so if a user select for example wednesday: 'closed', the till and from select boxes (list items in this `.time_row`) are hiding.

My HTML for each day:

```
<div class="time_row">
    <label>Monday:</label>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="open">Open</option>
            <option value="closed">Closed</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        From:
    </li>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
            <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
            etc
        </select>
    </li>   
    <li>
        Till:
    </li>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
            <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
            etc
        </select>
    </li>       
</div><!--End time_row-->
```

I have tried to make it with jQuery `.slice()` but then he hides all list elements after this select box and before?

```
// Account time table
$('.time_row select').change( function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 'closed' ) {
        $('.time_row li').slice(3).hide();  
    }
});
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Give a `name` or class to your `select` elements so you can differentiate which select does what.

Comment: Yes I have in my website. I output them with a loop for each day. But for this example I kept it simple.

Comment: I would include those attributes in this sample...they do make a difference in the answers you'll receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like that:

```
$('.time_row').find('select:first').change(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('.time_row')
        .find('li')
        .slice(1)
        .toggle(this.value === 'open');
}).change();
```

In this case on `change` event you search for the `<select>` closest parent element with class `.time_row`. Then pick up all inner `<li>` elements, remove the first from the list with `slice(1)` and either show or hide the rest upon the condition `this.value === 'open'`.

You should also check your markup and put all `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` to make it valid.

In the **updated** answer I have included the correct selector to select only first `<select>` elements (ignoring time selectors) and added the *by default* state with triggering `change` event after binding.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mPNCA/1/

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: @Robbert I have added some description in the updated answer.

Comment: Very thanks for your explanation! Now I only need to hide the element without the `.change()`, so if 'closed' is selected the element are gone and if select 'open'. Can I make a simple if statement for this?

Comment: @Robbert You mean to show/hide by default on page load?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Robbert This is rather easy: just trigger the `change` event right after binding. See the updated answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (untested):

```
$(".time_row select:first").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "closed") {
        $(this).closest(".time_row").find("select").not(this).hide();
    }
});
```